# flutter navigation pop always pop to root

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new on flutter and I got a problem with navigation pop system. I don't understand what's wrong on my code but what should I check on my code if every time I pressed back button on phone(not on AppBar or anything else), it goes back to the root of my page, not the previous page. but it works perfectly when I press back using the app bar back button that created automatically.

I've tried to fix this issue by passing some unpassed BuildContext to my separated widget hoping that's the problem but still doesn't works

Example:
I have three pages A, B, C

A->B->C

A->B->D

A->B->E

when I press smartphone's back button on B it goes to A (works).

when I press Scaffold appbar back button on C it goes to B (still works),

But, when I press smartphone's back button on C, D, or E it goes to A (not works)

```dart
//this is where I initialize my route
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
      '/main': (BuildContext context) => MainPage(),
      // '/b': (BuildContext context) => MyPage(title: 'page B'),
      // '/c': (BuildContext context) => MyPage(title: 'page C'),
    },
.....


// and this is how I push 
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/main');
}
```

Comment: Just use  `Navigator.of(context).pop();` it will pop to previous page in the stack

Comment: @SergioBernal I didn't initialize that on my code because the back button that created automatically by scaffold do the works. But i still dont understand when i use my smartphone's back button i doest work the same as the one that scaffold create :)

Comment: Ok I see. And what happens if you push to "page B" then to "page C" and then press the phone back button?

Comment: @SergioBernal I've updated my question above with some extra explanation. Thanks for keep helping

Comment: Did you try running your project in iOS to see if the same behavior happens?

Comment: Do you have a MaterialApp widget in every page?

Comment: @SergioBernal currently I can't compile on IOS because I don't have MAC . and I don't have MaterialApp on every page I have. does it have to? I can't test right now but ill be right back

Comment: @HassanSaleh I don't have MaterialApp on every page I have (in my Example, page C use Scaffold as widget root, not a material app). does it have to? I can't test right now but ill be right back

Comment: @HassanSaleh I tried to wrap my whole Scaffold and its body on a material app, still doesn't work and the Scaffold automated back button doesn't show up

Comment: If you share the full code, it will be easier to help because we can test your code in our machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HassanSaleh giving me a little clue about the material app. I have misunderstood about using material app route. I initialize material app route on every page and I read carefully on flutter dev cookbook about navigating page and found out that I should just put materialapp only on the very top of my widget stack. So the fix for me is **Removed material app on every widget and only put one material app and its route on very root app Widget**. Maybe I have bad explanation hope u guys understand